# Installing axios using npm is undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, axios

I am new to Axios and I am dealing with my first issue! I installed it with

```
npm install axios
```

and I get this error!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwqWu.png)

Also, I get an ENOENT error: no such file or directory, open /path/../../../
Can someone explain the reason?

Thank you!

**UPDATED**:

I no longer get the ENOENT error.

**THE FIX**:

Was to change the name directory to something else rather than axios to axiosapi or anything else!

**NEW ISSUE** :

```
const axios = require('axios');

const api_url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1';
console.log(api_url);


axios.get(api_url)
.then(
    response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response);
        }
        return response;
    }
)
.then( response => console.log(response) )

.catch( err =>  console.log(err) )
```

[Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at axioss.js:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw6nX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing globally use npm install -g axios.

Otherwise you need to create a project in your current directory: `npm init -y`

Comment: Thank you very much! And what is the use of -y flag?

Comment: I found it! Its just uses the default parameters of npm without the inquire at the beginning

Comment: hi @user789703 it does not work still! The same issue but the npm init -y worked just fine! All the node modules along with axios were succesfully installed!