# how to resolve the reference error on require when i use it to import axios API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to implement some axios projects(beginer level) and i get this reference errror that require is not defined?
I have already inserted it using

```
npm install axios require
```

[SCREENSHOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nckvo.png)

Any ideas what might failed?

I have also created a post with additional issues i dealed with inserting axios [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936927/installing-axios-using-npm-is-undefined)!

Comment: Anything could fail. I'm positive you don't need to install `require`. Why is the question labeled with RequireJS? If you use it with Node, this is a mistake. The problem depends on your Webpack configuration and other build details which aren't presented in the question. You don't need to use `require()` in an app that is bundled with Webpack, use `import` instead. Webpack config file name has a typo.

Comment: so requirejs is not relevant with my problem? Is webpack neccesary for require and import to work? And if so do i need babel? Since import is an ES6 module?

Comment: No, it is not relevant.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined